# Not seeing Quill editor in active admin form

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

Not seeing Quill editor in active admin form.

followed all instructions from [here](https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_quill_editor) and the whole description box doesn't diplay. same happened to other editors i tried.

```
form title: "Drinks" do |f|
  f.inputs "Drinks" do
    f.input :title
    f.input :description, as: :quill_editor
    f.input :steps
    f.input :source
  end
  f.actions
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure you have included active_admin/base to your app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js file:

```
//= require active_admin/base
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor/quill
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor_input
```

This is what was causing the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented Quill Rich Text Editor in Active Admin by following the below steps in Rails 6 application:

Add the gems:

```
gem 'activeadmin_quill_editor'
gem 'sassc'
```

Add below js code in app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js:

```
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor/quill
//= require activeadmin/quill_editor_input
```

Add below css code in app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.scss

```
@import 'activeadmin/quill_editor/quill.snow';
@import 'activeadmin/quill_editor_input';
```

For defualt toolbar options use the below syntax:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Notices' do
    f.input :description, as: :quill_editor
  end
  f.actions
end
```

For customized toolbar options the use below syntax:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs 'Notices' do
    f.input :description, as: :quill_editor, input_html: { data: { options: { modules: { toolbar: [ ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],['blockquote', 'code-block'],  [{ 'header': 1 }, { 'header': 2 }], [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }], [{ 'script': 'sub'}, { 'script': 'super' }], [{ 'indent': '-1'}, { 'indent': '+1' }], [{ 'direction': 'rtl' }], [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }], [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }], [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }], [{ 'font': [] }], [{ 'align': [] }], ['clean'] ] }, theme: 'snow' } } }
  end
  f.actions
end
```

For more information visit:

- https://github.com/blocknotes/activeadmin_quill_editor
- https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/

Answer (score 0):

```
// To view the variables that Active Admin provides, take a look at
// `app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin/mixins/_variables.scss` in the
// Active Admin source
// For example, to change the sidebar width:
// Needs to be done when default CSS was overriden 
// use this in SCSS file  
    @import "active_admin/mixins";
    @import "active_admin/base";
    @import 'activeadmin/quill_editor/quill.snow';
    @import 'activeadmin/quill_editor_input';
```

Comment: thanks for the code snippet. but can you explain what someone should do with this?